# amchart bar chart disappears when scrolling

Tags: javascript, angular, amcharts

i am using amchart version `4.7.18` i created chart with datetime axis , and my category-axis is like this value is  `series.dataFields.dateX = 'datetime';` when i am scrolling chart disappears i used reverse method but it does not work for me i attached image below  [chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM9T4.png)

```
{ "hsk":"primary",
  "elapsed_mins":0,
  "bctx_change":3,
  "carton_qty":0,
  "subject":"ant-aal-aepz-floor1-sewing-section1-line2",
  "ftt":0,
  "completed":0,
  "defectives":0,
  "pack_qty":0,
  "total":0,
  "module_id":"Team02",
  "checkin":0,
  "section_id":"SectionA",
  "total_rejects":0,
  "domRole_dn":"Endline QC",
  "member":0,
  "evttime":"6:1",
  "reworked":0,
  "grouped_timing":"2020-02-04T00:00:00.000Z",
  "datetime":"2020-07-24T06:01:42.117Z"
}
```